# How to run get the text selected on a webview and clip it in android?

Tags: android, webview, textselection

Hi I am working on a project to clip the data from web and add it to the cloud and ihave  have gone thorugh this https://github.com/bossturbo/WebViewMarker/blob/master/samples/demos/.project example and it does pretty much all that needs to be done in terms of text selection. But the example explains how to do it on a local html file. I need to implement the same on any website(Facebook Google, SO what ever ) that the user would visit and be able to clip the data on to the clipboard. Long story short, I need to modify this code(library) to do 2 things.

1. provide text selection on a webview for all the websites.
2. This project highlights the text after the user releases the button.
   I need to make it perform this as the user drags the cursor.

**Any help would be appreciated and my project rests on this. The client need to be told the estimates for this and i am stuck for 3 days**